# The "Get Started" section in the sidebar only mentions API 2.0 and API 1.1

Tags: bug, discussion, status-completed, api-v2.1

Now that [API 2.1 is "public, frozen, and out the door"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/09/stack-exchange-api-v2-1/) shouldn't we update the "Get Started" section in the sidebar on the right side of the screen.

It talks about API 2.0 and API 1.1 but doesn't mention our spiffy new API.

<sup>(It's similar to a documentation bug in some ways so I tagged it [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) in lieu of any other good ideas and no meta site for this SE.)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The little sidebar block will refer to API V2.1 starting with the next build.